# Hibernate implementation by pass in different types of params

Tags: java, hibernate

So I am able to get Company information by passing in Company ID with Hibernate, code is as follows:

```
public Company getCompanyById(Integer companyId) {
    Company company = (Company) getCurrentSession().get(Company.class, companyId);
    return company;
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is to pass in company name, address and cell phone number to get the company. The method in my mind is like this:

```
 public Company getCompanyByNameAddressCellphone(String companyName, String address, Integer cellPhoneNumber);
```

How do I implement it?

Comment: multiple way to query database using hibernate - hql query, Criteria APi, SQL query

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder can you post a detailed answer for this?

Comment: Hibernate Documentation [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/index.html) - 1. [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) 2. [Criteria API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html)
3. [SQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate Criteria to achieve this. It would look something like:

```
public Company getCompanyByNameAddressCellphone(String companyName, String address, Integer cellPhoneNumber) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyName", companyName));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("address", address));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cellPhoneNumber", cellPhoneNumber));
    return criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

In this scenario, the String values provided to the `Restrictions#eq` call are the property names of your Company entity.

If you don't want to match exact String values and prefer using `like`, you can use `Restrictions#like` or `Restrictions#ilike` (case insensitive version).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Criteria/DetachedCriteria or HQL.  A `Criteria` instance or a `Query` instance can both be retrieved from the session (referenced by the same `getCurrentSession()` call in your example).

Not sure what version of Hibernate you're working with, but here is the documentation on querying: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying

the key points are that your property names (Company.name, Company.address, etc.) are used to query rather than the DB column names, which your code shouldn't be expected to know.

My personal preference is for DetachedCriteria.  Used with the Restrictions API, you can accomplish about 85% of your querying needs.  DetachedCriteria's execution flow is slightly different and documented here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries